# How to add text at the start of each paragraph (e.g. a paragraph mark)

Tags: paragraphs

I want to add a mark (e.g. `X` or `¶`) at the start of each paragraph which is inside a custom environment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand{\sometext}{
  This is some text

  This is some text in a new paragraph.

  This is even more text in yet another new paragraph
}
\newenvironment{paragraphmarked}{%
  % Magic command goes here?
}{%
  % Maybe reset paragraph behaviour here?
}
\begin{document}
\begin{paragraphmarked}
  \sometext
\end{paragraphmarked}
\end{document}
```

### What I currently see:

[image: What I currently see]

### What I would like to have

[image: What I want to see]

---

I tried doing

```
\let\oldpar\par
\let\par{\par X}
% Text goes here
\let\par\oldpar
```

But this resulted in TeX running out of memory in my (rather large) document.

Comment: `\let\par{\oldpar X}`,   untested, your version with `\let\par{\par X}` will result in an infinite loop...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the TeX command `\everypar{...}` for exactly that purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\everypar{X}

Text

Text

Text

\end{document}
```

By means of a user-defined environment, the scope of `\everypar{}` can be limited:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{paragraphmarked}[1]{\everypar{#1}}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{paragraphmarked}{X}
Text

Text

Text
\end{paragraphmarked}

Text

Text

Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent! I presume one can do `\everypar{}` to cancel this effect with any problems? Also, where is this feature documented?

Comment: If you define an environment, you may limit the scope of the command. See edit.

Comment: Documented in "The TeXbook", I suppose.