# Putting chapter like numbers at the beginning of article

Tags: article

> I am writing an article by just simply using `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,onesided]{article}`. I would like to know how can I put the number 1 that appears at the very beginning of a paragraph in the picture:

[image]

> This is not a thesis or something related, it is just a simple article containing four pages.

Comment: An article does not have chapters.

Comment: You get the idea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create documents in LaTeX using a calligraphic first letter for chapters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/769/how-can-i-create-documents-in-latex-using-a-calligraphic-first-letter-for-chapte)

Comment: @naveganTeX do you want the numbering to be automatic or do you want to provide the number manually? Unrelated: in English the singular of 'matrices' is normally 'matrix' and not 'matrice' (but maybe you have a good reason to use 'matrice', I don't know).

Comment: I would love the numbering to be automatic! How can I achieve that? Regarding "Matrice", the text is from a friend of mine, I did not write it. I just took it to illustrate what I wanted.

Comment: @naveganTeX: See [How to add text at the start of each paragraph (e.g. a paragraph mark)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422118/5764). But `\par` is used in many other places, not just for introducing a paragraph break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lettrine{\sffamily 1}{} \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Haha, you're the one! Thank you very much! If I could, I would be doing up-voting for you with bots, but I'm afraid it is not possible, is it? haha

Comment: @naveganTeX Thanks! But *please* do not do serial upvoting. Such votes defeat the purpose and will be reversed anyway. Upvote any post which you like, regardless of who wrote it. (See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8184/how-can-one-politely-ask-unknown-users-to-consider-stopping-serial-votings.)

Comment: I know! I was only kidding. It is just a way of showing my gratitude to you for the hand you give me.

Comment: @naveganTeX You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Extending the [nice answer by marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/497288/) here a solution with automatic numbering. It works by defining a new counter `lettrinectr`, initially with value 1, and a macro `\lettrinenext` is defined to be used for each paragraph that prints the current number and increases the counter by one.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{lettrinectr}
\setcounter{lettrinectr}{1}
\newcommand{\lettrinenext}{%
\lettrine{\sffamily \thelettrinectr}{} %
\stepcounter{lettrinectr}%
}

\begin{document}
\lettrinenext \lipsum[1]
\lettrinenext \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]