# TikZ Overlay: Inject content at the start of the next paragraph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, paragraphs, white-space

### Problem Statement

I'd like to conditionally add a TikZ overlay at the start of some paragraphs or figures.

[image: Failed attempt to draw red boxes around the first letter of each paragraph]

In this example (see code below), I'd like to conditionally insert red boxes around the first character of "Paragraph 3" and "External file". However, because the external file contains empty lines, TeX sets my overlay picture in a separate paragraph on its own. One may argue that I should simply put the `\RedBox` command into `figure1.tex`, just in font of the actual content. However, let's assume for the sake of argument that the included files are provided externally and can not easily be modified.

The problem is that the red box is not around the first character, because the `\tikz` command starts a new paragraph. I think this is because it forces TeX to enter horizontal mode or something. More details can be found in the question [Tikzpicture with overlay takes up space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22873/tikzpicture-with-overlay-takes-up-space).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\RedBox{\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (0.6em, 1em);}

\begin{filecontents}{figure1.tex}
% Some random definitions which may or may not contain whitespace or newlines
\def\MyHelperMacro{foo}

External file which may or may not contain empty lines. \MyHelperMacro
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

Paragraph 1 bla bla

Paragraph 2 bla bla

% Here the overlay works as expected
\RedBox
Paraghraph 3 bla bla.

% Here the overlay starts a new paragraph, which is undesired!
\RedBox
\input{figure1.tex}

Paragraph 5
\end{document}
```

### Not a Solution

The question [Tikzpicture with overlay takes up space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22873/tikzpicture-with-overlay-takes-up-space) explains why this is the case and why it can't be fixed easily (allegedly because the `\tikz` command creates a *'whatsit'*, whatever that may be). It is suggested to use `\nointerlineskip`, but that doesn't solve the problem, neither in the `\RedBox` command (as shown below) nor in the included file (which is sometimes infeasible; output is still wrong, but not shown here).

```
\def\RedBox{\nointerlineskip\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (0.6em, 1em);}
```

[image: Using \nointerlineskip doesn't fix the problem]

### Partial Solution?

So I thought, it it were possible to store the `\tikz` command somewhere and emit it only when a new paragraph is started by some **other** following content, then it wouldn't start a new a paragraph on its own. [As it turns out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422118/12440), there is `\everypar{stuff}` which prepends `stuff` to all following paragraphs. So the following achieves the desired effect, but still has some problems.

```
\def\RedBox{%
    \everypar{%
        \tikz[overlay, remember picture] \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (0.6em, 1em);%
        \everypar{}%
    }%
}
```

[image: Working but inflexible solution]

For example, if you added a second command `\GreenCircle` which uses the same mechanism, you can't have both a `\RedBox` and a `\GreenCircle` on the same paragraph because the second one erases the `\everypar` that was set by the first command. And if you had another package which sets `\everypar`, then it gets messed up the first time you use one of the overlay commands.

So finally, after a lot of setup and explanation, we get to the actual question:

**Is there a better way to inject content at the start of the next paragraph, which doesn't mess up other usages of `\everypar`?**

Answer (score 2):

How about really inserting a picture at the beginning of every paragraph but just change its contents with the macros like `\RedBox`, `\GreenCircle` and so on?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents}{figure1.tex}
% Some random definitions which may or may not contain whitespace or newlines
\def\MyHelperMacro{foo}

External file which may or may not contain empty lines. \MyHelperMacro
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\ResetPar}{\tikzset{every par/.code={}}}
\newcommand\RedBox{\tikzset{every par/.append code={\draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (0.6em,
1em);}}}
\newcommand\GreenCircle{\tikzset{every par/.append code={\draw[green!70!black] (0.3em,0.4em)
 circle[x radius=0.3em,y radius=0.4em];}}}

\ResetPar
\begin{document}
\everypar{%
        \tikz[overlay, remember picture]{
        \tikzset{every par}
%       \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (0.6em, 1em);%
        }%
    }%


Paragraph 1 bla bla

Paragraph 2 bla bla

% Here the overlay works as expected
\RedBox
Paraghraph 3 bla bla.

% Here the overlay starts a new paragraph, which is undesired!
%\RedBox
\input{figure1.tex}
\ResetPar

Paragraph 5

\GreenCircle
Paraghraph 6 bla bla.

% Here the overlay starts a new paragraph, which is undesired!
%\RedBox
\input{figure1.tex}
\ResetPar

Paragraph 7

\RedBox\GreenCircle
Paraghraph 8 bla bla.

% Here the overlay starts a new paragraph, which is undesired!
%\RedBox
\input{figure1.tex}
\ResetPar

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good idea. You could probable make it a little more flexible by using a token list instead of a `tikzpicture` with `.append code`, thus allowing any TeX code to be added at the start of the next paragraph. But it would still break if someone else or some package uses `\everypar` for a different purpose. Also, I'd put `\ResetPar` into the `\everypar` code, because In my case it shouldn't repeat by default.