# Having single column footnotes in a twocolumn document without multicol

Tags: footnotes, two-column, multicolumn

I am writing a document with `\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{paper}`
In this document I am using a lot of `\footnote{}`. For the sake of having a neat lay-out I want the footnotes to span over both columns (so a single column footnote in  a twocolumn document).

The only sollution I found online was using `\usepackage{multicol}` and `\begin{2}{multicolumn}`
This did work, however the `multicol` package causes a lot of other issues with other floats in my document, so I am looking for a different solution. Below is a working example

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{paper}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1] \footnote{\lipsum[2]} \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Please see the intended result in green:

[image: intended result]

**p.s.**
This question is asked numerous times on several forums, however all of them have remained unanswered, so I figure I would try again myself.

**p.p.s.**
There is also a solution involving \mathfootnote but this does not seem to work for normal footnotes

Comment: Welcome. // Can you please have a look if my screenshot matches your intention?

Comment: You might also look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611262/footnotes-in-tcolorbox-not-in-the-page-of-the-footnotemark,  If you know what the footnote will be before the page it is on, you could put it into a bottom float*.

Comment: @MS-SPO This screenshot captures exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

Using separate `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`, you could manually delay the footnote until it **has** to split over two columns.  Not exactly what you were looking for, but closer.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{paper}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]\footnotemark 
  
  \lipsum[3]
  \footnotetext{\lipsum[2]}
  \lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```