Footnote appears on the page where the solution begins (exam class)
I want to add footnotes to the solution of an exam question, which I wrote using the exam class.
I followed this Stackexchange answer and wrote the following code.
\documentclass[answers]{exam}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{etextools,etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{solution}{%
  \let\oldfootnote\footnote% Store original footnote
  \renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{% Update \footnote
    \oldfootnote{#1}% Original footnote
    \ifprintanswers
      \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\AfterGroup{\noexpand\footnotetext[\thefootnote]{#1}}}\x%
    \fi
  }%
}

%\noprintanswers

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question[10] \lipsum [1-10] \begingroup\color{red}Where is the footnote for the question located?\endgroup\footnote{The same page.}
\begin{solution}
    \lipsum[11-20] \begingroup\color{red}Where is the footnote for the solution located?\endgroup\footnote{The page where the solution begins! :(}
\end{solution}

\end{questions}

\end{document}

I expected the footnote for the solution to appear on page 3, but it appears on page 2 where the solution begins. Is there a way to remedy this issue?




If you used a minipage type footnote, it would show up inside the solution, but minipages are not breakable.  You could store the footnote and page number in the aux file ( see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611262/footnotes-in-tcolorbox-not-in-the-page-of-the-footnotemark/611437?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C28.9765#611437).

In your particular case, using \footnotemark and \footnotetext resolves the issue.
\documentclass[answers]{exam}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{etextools,etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{solution}{%
  \let\oldfootnote\footnote% Store original footnote
  \renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{% Update \footnote
    \oldfootnote{#1}% Original footnote
    \ifprintanswers
      \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\AfterGroup{\noexpand\footnotetext[\thefootnote]{#1}}}\x%
    \fi
  }%
}

%\noprintanswers

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question[10] \lipsum [1-10] \begingroup\color{red}Where is the footnote for the question located?\endgroup\footnote{The same page.}
\begin{solution}
    \lipsum[11-20] \begingroup\color{red}Where is the footnote for the solution located?\endgroup\footnotemark
\end{solution}
\ifprintanswers\footnotetext{The page where the solution begins! :(}\fi
\end{questions}

\end{document}

Also see this for a more generalized solution.
