\footnote doesn't work inside of \mathrel, at least with amsart, hyperref, and amsrefs
Generally, using \footnote inside of an equation works as you'd expect.  However, when trying to attach a footnote number to a relation operator, I wrapped \mathrel around the operator and a \footnote.  The result was that the footnote number showed in the PDF but the footnote itself didn't.  LaTeX reported "warning (dest): name{Hfootnote.NNN} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one"
The naive code is
$a
\mathrel{\leq\footnote{Footnote attached to something inside of mathrel.}}
b$


In general, it's better to avoid footnoting parts of equations because footnotes (and the alternative traditional footnote symbols) all look like various math operations.  However, if you do:

I have only dealt with this situation in documentclass amsart.  I don't know how it translates to other documentclasses.

The problem only appears if I load both packages hyperref and amsrefs.  I haven't investigated why these are significant.



Footnotes use \insert, which can only be use locally (not global).  In other words, you cannot put a footnote inside a group of any kind.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314375/why-does-parbox-lose-footnotes?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C24.7864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611262/footnotes-in-tcolorbox-not-in-the-page-of-the-footnotemark

A workable solution is
\pdfoutput=1

\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsrefs}

\begin{document}

$a\footnote{This footnote works as expected.}
\mathrel{\leq\mskip-\thickmuskip\footnotemark}%
\footnotetext{Fix for footnote attached to something inside of mathrel.}
b$

\end{document}


Note the use of \mskip-\thickmuskip after \leq.  \leq is a relation operator and so gets an \mskip\thickmuskip after it before the footnote number.  When attaching a footnote number to the operator, this is undesirable.  Hence the \mskip to remove that space.

Using \footnotemark and \footnotetext without the optional arguments does what you want it to:  \footnotemark increments the footnote counter and \footnotetext uses the current value of the footnote counter.

Since \footnote works as expected in math mode outside of \mathrel, the \footnotemark can be placed immediately after \mathrel to ensure it is placed on the same page and also that nothing modifies the footnote counter between \footnotemark and \footnotetext.



Don't use footnotes in math formulas, because the only certain consequence is that readers will be confused: maybe a second or third reading could remove the confusion, but why inflicting the pain?
Anyway, if you really want to attach a footnote to a relation symbol, do
\mathrel{{\leq}\footnotemark}\footnotetext{Text of the footnote}

If you have several such footnotes, make your life easier
\newcommand{\footnoterel}[2]{%
  \mathrel{{#1}\footnotemark}\footnotetext{#2}%
}

to be called like
$a \footnoterel{\leq}{Text of the footnote}b$

Example
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\footnoterel}[2]{%
  \mathrel{{#1}\footnotemark}\footnotetext{#2}%
}

\setlength{\textheight}{2.5cm} % for a smaller picture

\begin{document}

$x \footnoterel{\geq}{For $x\ge0$.} \lvert x\rvert$

$x \footnoterel{\geq}{For $x\ge0$.}\sin x$

\end{document}


Utterly confusing.
